# How search for thousands of possible keywords in a string

Tags: php, mysql, performance, keyword

I have a database of thousands (about 10,000) keywords. When a user posts a blog on my site, I would like to automatically search for the keywords in the text, and tag the post with any direct matches.

So far, all I can think of is to pull the ENTIRE list of keywords, loop through it, and check for the presence of each tag in the post...which seems very inefficient (that's 10,000 loops).

Is there a more common way to do this? Should I maybe use a MySQL query to limit it down?

I imagine this is not a totally rare task.

Comment: Good question - this will help a bunch of people (myself included!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, just don't do that.

Instead of looping through 10000 elements, it is better to extract the words from the sentence or text, then add it to the SQL query and that way you will have all the needed records. This is surely more efficient than the solution you proposed.

You can do this in the following way using PHP:

```
$possible_keywords = preg_split('/\b/', $your_text, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The above will split the text on the words' boundaries and will return no empty elements in the array.

Then you just can create the SQL query in a fashion similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE `keywords`.`keyword` IN (...)
```

(just put the comma-separated list of extracted words in the bracket)

You should probably filter the `$possible_keywords` array before making the query (to include only the keywords with appropriate length and to exclude duplicates) plus make `keyword` column indexed.

Comment: So, maybe gather related tags from the db with a FULLTEXT search first, which should narrow them down to 100 max, and then loop? Or were you thinking something different?

Comment: +1 I like this answer - I had one of those "duh!" moments reading this.

Comment: @johnnietheblack No, I was thinking about extracting the words from the text (I do not know how long the text may be, though), then filtering the result (to exclude too short, too long and duplicated words) and then passing it to SQL query to execute only one query that will return any keyword that may be applied to the given text. Of course there are many alternatives, but I thought you wanted to get all the keywords contained within the specific text and in the database - and the proposed solution is the most efficient I can think of now.

Comment: Assume the user posted "Hi my name is John". Then you should query the database like this: `SELECT * from keywords WHERE keyword IN ('hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John')`. Make sure the table has an index on `keyword`

Comment: @Jakob This is exactly what I had in mind and described. Using that is much more efficient than making 10000 steps checking each of the keywords from the database, don't you think? ;) Also if keywords in the database aren't eg. shorter than 4 characters, you can filter off all the elements that are shorter, simplifying the query to the form of `... IN ('name', 'John')`. I hope this is some good starting point to optimize the feature OP wanted to create.

Comment: @Tadeck, yes, I just saw you extended your answer. BTW, you should change the preg_split-code to `preg_split('/\\PL+/u', $your_text)`, because the word boundary assertion doesn't work in this case, and even if it would work, it would work only with ASCII characters. Not good for a website where everything should be UTF8!

Comment: @Jakob I think you mean `preg_split('/\P{L}+/u', $your_text, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`, correct? Also worth mentioning is that it will get only keywords consisting of letters, thus instead of getting `Windows7` keyword, it will get `Windows` keyword. Or am I missing something? But I think you are 100% correct about need to match all the UTF-8 letter characters.

Comment: @Tadeck The braces are optional, but you are right that numbers are not matched. One could use `'/[^\pL\pN_-]+\/'` to get letters and numbers and the hyphen and underscore. I'm not sure what kind of keywords the OP uses. For some reason, the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` thing doesn't work for me (it doesn't split at all), but that might just be a problem with my specific install of PHP.

Comment: WOW this question really took off on me. What about if my tags have multiple words in them....like "John M", would the MySQL "IN" statement work as effectively?

Comment: for example - if it was splitting all the words by their spaces, then it would try and compare "John" and "M" to the tag "John M" and that would fail, yes?

Comment: @johnnietheblack No, if your 'keyword' is not actually a 'word', but rather an expression (like 'John M'), then this solution will not suit you. But in this case you the solution will be a lot less efficient and would involve checking for different groups of words occuring one after another. There are some solutions for you, however: 1) avoid using 'keywords' consisting of multiple words or treat them separately (this solution is widely applied), 2) treat them separately (if you have to, make a loop on the 'keywords' from db containing spaces - but only on them, the rest was described).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what language you intend on using, but a standard [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (prefix tree) would solve this issue, if you were feeling up to it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could build a regular expression dynamically which will enable you to match keywords inside a specific string. You can package all this in a class which does the grunt work.

```
class KeywordTagger {
  static function getTags($body) {
    if(preg_match_all(self::getRegex(), $body, $keywords)) {
      return $keywords[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static $regex;
  private static function getRegex() {
    if(self::$regex === null) {
      // Load Keywords from DB here
      $keywords = KeywordsTable::getAllKeywords();

      // Let's escape
      $keywords = array_map('KeywordTagger::pregQuoteWords', $keywords);

      // Base Regex
      $regex = '/\b(?:%s)\b/ui';

      // Build Final
      self::$regex = sprintf($regex, implode('|', $keywords));
    }

    return self::$regex;
  }

  private static function pregQuoteWords($word) {
    return preg_quote($word, '/');
  }
}
```

Then, all you have to do is, when a user writes a post, run it through the class:

```
$tags = KeywordTagger::getTags($_POST['messageBody']);
```

For a small speed up, you could cache the built regex using memcached, APC or a good-old file-based cache.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that PHP's stripos is already quite optimized. If you want to optimize this search further, you would have to take advantage of similarities between your keywords (e.g. instead of looking for "foobar" and then for "foobaz", look for "fooba" and then check for each "fooba" if it's followed by a 'r', a 'z', or none). But this would require some sort of tree-representation of your keywords, like:

root (empty string)

```
 |

fooba

/  \
```

foobar   foobaz

Yes, that's a trie.